# Laravel nova file download not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Having some issues with downloading from a 'file' field in a resource out of a sudden. Definitely used to work! When clicking download it says

'Failed server problem.'

In the logs it says:

'ERROR: File not found at path: invoice.pdf'

The file definitely exists in the storage folder and I can publicly access it by manually inputting the URL.

Storage link exists, disk has been set.

'File::make('Invoice', 'file')->disk('public')->hideWhenCreating(),'

I tried editing nova core as I thought it is not looking for the right path and manually adding the proper storage path and it still acts like it doesn't exist.

"ERROR: File not found at path: home/forge/site.com/storage/app/public/invoice.pdf"

But it's clearly in there! It worked before on live, it works on my local. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your path might be correct but you might have forgot add the symlink. On the server run this command.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This will create proper symlinks and you won't have the File Not Found issue.

Comment: Already did that unfortunately "The "public/storage" directory already exists."